# How to extend acumatica api to attach file in Sales order Line Item

Tags: rest, acumatica

I am able to attach file in the #acumatica sales order by rest api. Is there any way to attach a file in sales order line item.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019R2 - I320 Web Services Data Manipulation training guide, this is not supported.  You must use the Screen-Based SOAP API's instead.

Per the training guide (page 90):

**Attachment of Files to Detail Lines**

This scenario is outside of the scope of this course but may be useful to some readers.
The attachment of files to detail lines is not supported by the available versions of system endpoints of the contract-based APIs. If you need to attach files to detail lines, you can use the screen-based SOAP API.

By using the screen-based SOAP API, you attach a file to a detail line on an Acumatica ERP form by using the Value command and the Attachment service command of the object that corresponds to the detail tab on the target form. For example, to attach a file to a warehouse detail of a stock item, you use the WarehouseDetails.ServiceCommands.Attachment service command. For details about the service commands, see [Commands for Working with Attachments](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(7))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=14f7053a-8c07-49fe-82fb-0c6fb1b459dc).

Comment: Thank you. Good to know it's at least possible via Screen api.